# Can we replace IP address with actual domain name?

Tags: php, dns

For example: I have accessed the page of my site with the 
URL: http://52.26.161.170/index.php?showLoginSignUp=true&id=51.

It displays the content of my page.

But when I was trying to access the page with my domain name like, http://www.your.co.uk/index.php?showLoginSignUp=true&id=51
It was not displaying the requested page, as i get (It displays the content of my page.).

Can we replace IP address with actual domain name in php?
please help me ,thanku.

Comment: Have you any domain name?

Comment: yes the actual domain name is yourtraceit.co.uk

Comment: ok, have purchase hosting

Comment: already it was hosted,if you have any sample code means ,plase add that .

Comment: I think you are not changed your domain's 'name server's Address'. Check on whois you current name server. this is like- Name Server: NS1.abc.INFO

Comment: ok i will try this ,tq

Comment: this address provide by your hosting company

Comment: "It was not displaying the requested page, as i get (It displays the content of my page.)." ? So it displays the wrong page?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

But first you must add a DNS record that will point your domain name to a desired IP address, and then you must configure your server. If you have paid hosting, that should all be done by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, you can also add a static name resolution in the hosts file.

This file should be in /etc/ on unix or in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc on windows.
Of course it'll work only on the system you put the hosts file in.

Hosts file have a simple syntax, juste add a line like this :

52.26.161.170          www.your.co.uk

Comment: localhost localhost.localdomain
52.26.161.170  yourtraceit.co.uk
127.0.0.1  yourtraceit.co.uk
 these are the contents of hosts file
 under /etc/

Comment: but the same is going on

Comment: It seems that it is the content of the server's hosts file. I was talking about the client's hosts file.